# Doctrine Setup Location of files

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.1

I set up Doctrine for my Symfony project using composer. I can create and use entitities in my development environement, but I cant use any of the nice command line tools.
The manual says, you need to set up *Bootstrap.php* and a *cli-config.php*. What the manual doesn't say is, where in the project these files belong to.
Any help about location of these files would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the Symfonry framework or use some of the components?  If you are using the framework then Bootstrap.php is not applicable: http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html

Comment: I am using the framework - thanks for the response. But how about cli-config.php. Where does this have to go to?

Comment: No where.  Read the link I gave you.  Symfony has it's own doctrine commands.